# Parsley.js - change error container

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I want to alter the positioning of each error message. That is display the error message in the respective `<div class="errorBlock"></div>`. By using the documentation's code the the error msg is displayed before the element (input) and not displayed as expected. 
Any ideas?

As per documentation:

```
errors: {
    container: function (element, isRadioOrCheckbox) {
        var $container = element.parent().find(".parsley-container");
        if ($container.length === 0) {
            $container = $("<div class='parsley-container'></div>").insertBefore(element);
        }
        return $container;
    }
}
```

My html code is:

**INPUT**

```
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">             
  <input class="form-control dataScrap firstInput" type="text" parsley-notblank="true" parsley-required="true" parsley-error-message="You must input a birth date" readonly="readonly"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
  <div class="errorBlock"></div>
</div>
```

**CHECKBOX**

```
<div class="checkbox-list">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" parsley-group="checkboxGroup" parsley-mincheck="2"> Checkbox 1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" parsley-group="checkboxGroup"> Checkbox 2
    </label>
    <div class="errorBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by overwriting [Parsley's default options](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html). (note: I'm talking about the latest version [v2.0], which I suggest you use) You basically want to give Parsley a method that will find the `.errorBlock` container based on the input field. It would look something like this:

```
var parsleyConfig = {
    errorsContainer: function(pEle) {
        var $err = pEle.$element.siblings('.errorBlock');
        return $err;
    }
}

$('#yourFormID').parsley(parsleyConfig);
```

And [here's a live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/urpKD).

Note: using this method you can't use the `parsley-validate` attribute that Makrand suggests. Calling `.parsley` on your form does the same thing, except you can add your custom options to it. Also, you need to prefix all of your parsley attributes with `data-`, because they're data attributes (as of v2.0).

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
data-parsley-errors-container=".errorBlock"
```

You can check this attribute in [Parsley Documentation](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html)

Comment: doesnt work here since there is <div class="errorBlock"></div> after each input element. parsley-error-container, will display all messages to the specified handler.

Comment: @andreas777 why don't you add a DIV at the top and provide a class to it to be used for parsley-error-container

Comment: @Makrand thats NOT the requirement. I want each error to be displayed (separately) in a div after each input element. And I want help on how to do this as per the documentation example... >> $container = $("<div class='parsley-container'></div>").insertBefore(element);

Comment: I want this to be dynamic and use the errors:{container} and NOT the parsley-error-container attribute

Comment: "~ .my-sibling-error-container" see here https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Your documentation link is broken and it's `data-parsley-errors-container`

Answer (score 8):

Parsley API has been updated. The current method is:

`data-parsley-errors-container="#your-div-id"`

See documentation here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field

Answer (score 0):

In reference to @ahmad hussain's answer you also need to put an attribute in your form:

> ```
> <form parsley-validate>
> ```